# How to display the value in a read only field which is returned from the function

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 input fields. when i mouse out from 3rd input field, sum of 3 input field values should be populated in 4th input field (kept in read only). How to do this using html and javascript?

Comment: Please provide the code you have as a [Minimal Reproduceable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It helps us help you when we can see your code and see what you have tried so far so we can correct where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [onmouseout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp) event to get the sum of all three fields. First create a method `getSum` and use it in `onmouseout` to execute.

```js
function getSum(){
    //Fetch value from all input fields
    let first  = document.getElementById('field1').value;
    let second = document.getElementById('field2').value;
    let third  = document.getElementById('field3').value;
    let fourth = document.getElementById('field4');

    //Calculate the sum 
    let sum = Number(first)+Number(second)+Number(third);

    //Assign the sum to the fourth field
    field4.value = sum;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
    <h3>Enter Number:</h3>
    <label>First:</label>
    <br> 
    <input type="number" id="field1">
    <br>
    <label>Second:</label>
    <br> 
    <input type="number" id="field2">
    <br>
    <label>Third:</label> 
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="field3" onmouseout="getSum()">
    <br>
    <label>Sum:</label>
    <br> 
    <input type="number" id="field4" disabled> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onmouseout event to call a javascript function that populates the 4th field.
For more info see here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mouseEvt(scope){
  let in1 =parseInt( document.querySelector('input[name=in1]').value);
  let in2 =parseInt( document.querySelector('input[name=in2]').value);
  let in3 =parseInt( document.querySelector('input[name=in3]').value);
  document.querySelector('input[name=in4]').value=in1+in2+in3;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="in1" readonly value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="in2" readonly value="1"/>
<input type="text" onmouseout="mouseEvt(this)" name="in3" readonly value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="in4" readonly/>
```